# Push container to bluemix registry: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

**docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/container_registry/[my_image_name]
Returns 405 Method Not Allowed.**

Here is my procedure:

I went through the instruction on how to add a container to bluemix:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/add-your-own/

First:
I logged in with:

```
cf login
cf ic login
```

The bluemix instruction did not mention an endpoint. I googled the endpoint and connected to https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Everything worked.
That is the output:

```
** Retrieving client certificates from IBM Containers
** Storing client certificates in /home/compute/.ice/certs
Successfully retrieved client certificates
** Checking local docker configuration
Not OK
Docker local daemon may not be running. You can still run IBM Containers on the cloud

There are two ways to use the CLI with IBM Containers:

Option 1) This option allows you to use cf ic for managing containers on IBM Containers while still using the docker CLI directly to manage your local docker host. 
Leverage this Cloud Foundry IBM Containers plugin without affecting the local docker environment:


Example Usage:
cf ic ps
cf ic images

Option 2) Leverage the docker CLI directly. In this shell, override local docker environment to connect to IBM Containers by setting these variables, copy and paste the following:
Notice: only commands with an asterisk(*) are supported within this option

export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/home/compute/.ice/certs
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

Example Usage:
docker ps
docker images</i>
```

After setting the DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_TLS the docker ps and docker image command gives me correct results.

Then, I re-write the tag of my container according to the instructions:

```
docker tag [my_image_name] registry.ng.bluemix.net/container_registry/[my_image_name]
```

Executing:

```
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/container_registry/[my_image_name]
```

Gives an error:

```
`Error response from daemon: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>`
```

I found the ./ibm-container script in the ~/.ice directory, which adds the authentication values to the docker command, the same error.

Without the certificate, I am asked name, password and email; It does not give me access with my bluemix credentials.

Comment: You need to ensure your local docker engine is configured properly and running. There was an error when you run cf ic login: Not OK
Docker local daemon may not be running

Comment: Are you actually trying to push to the container_registry registry?

Comment: As @whitfiea says - if you're pushing to .../container_registry/... then you won't be allowed access. You need to replace this string with your own registry. e.g.
registry.ng.bluemix.net/joebloggs/image1

Comment: I called the registry (container_registry). And the Docker daemon runs locally, I can execute docker  ps successfully. I can also execute docker ps/images on the remote Docker daemon.

Answer (score 1):

as described in previous comments there are you problems in your description:
- check your docker daemon settings as suggested by @adasilva, it seems not running, it won't prevent you tagging images on Bluemix, but it would be better for you to make it run locally too
- according to your description you are using a registry name "container_registry" and it shouldn't be your one (unless you successfully registered it): you can retrieve it using

```
cf ic info
```

Then substitute your registry to "container_registry": now you should be able to tag/push on Bluemix containers

Comment: I registered my container_registry with the name "container_registry". I solved the local docker daemon issue by adding my current user to the docker group. It shows: ** Checking local docker configuration
OK
** Authenticating with registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
Successfully authenticated with registry -- The error is still the same though.

Comment: cf ic info provides me with: namespace                : container_registry.The other information are correct, like the current project and the username.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you were able to get past this error.  I'm seeing the same behavior on my mac.  I can start with a local docker instance and run commands.  When I run cf ic login, I see Checking local Docker configuration...
Your system was authenticated with the IBM Containers API,
however the local Docker daemon is not reachable to authenticate it
with the IBM Containers registry. You can still run IBM Containers
on the cloud but will not be able to push or pull images.  From there I get  405 errors when I try to run commands such as docker tag.  Thanks!

Comment: TOW and @JT-user2216025
Hello, in order to use the docker client with remote Bluemix containers api you have to have to switch to Bluemix containers api on the your docker env, like described by cf ic login output

export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=[a value for your env]
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

Only when your docker references have been update to work remotely on Bluemix, you will be able to run docker commands on Bluemix containers api instead of your local docker env

Comment: Hi V,  I exported the Docker env variables as per the output from the cf ic login command.   Note I am working on a Mac.  I used the export command and if I run env | grep -i docker, I see the env variables set in my environment.  Thanks!